# Not able to add foreign key in MySql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE1` (
  `TABLE_ID1` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TABLE_ID1`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `TABLE2` (
  `LOCAL_CUST_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `TABLE_ID1` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Both table created successfully in MySql but while trying adding foreign key by below Alter statement then getting below issue.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE2
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ID FOREIGN KEY(TABLE_ID1) REFERENCES TABLE1(TABLE_ID1);

Error Code: 1452
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`#sql-7fcd_79`, CONSTRAINT `FK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`TABLE_ID1`) REFERENCES `TABLE1` (`TABLE_ID1`))
```

In both table I have used different engine.

Can someone please help what I am not able to add foreign key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation:

> [13.1.18.6 Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)
>
> ...
>
> Foreign keys definitions are subject to the following conditions:
>
> ...
>
> - ... The parent and child tables must use the same storage engine. ...
>
> ...

Comment: If I am trying to change engine then its saying table already exist. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty: Try `ALTER TABLE \`TABLE1\` ENGINE=InnoDB;`, after, `ALTER TABLE \`TABLE2\`
ADD CONSTRAINT ...`.